# URLUtil.isHttpsUrl() wrong return value in Simple Unittest? (returnDefaultValues=true)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

Maybe this is the most ridiculous question ever, or I just can't think straight anymore - but I have experienced a very strange behaviour when using the `URLUtil.isHttpsUrl()` from `android.webkit`.

I was writing some Unittests for my project and detected that a method returned an unexpected value, because the URL was not considered valid.

Trying to narrow things down, I ended up with a simple testcase like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testSimpleHttpsCheck() {
      String url = "https://www.this.ishttps.com";
      Assert.assertTrue(isHttpsUrl(url)); // returns true
      Assert.assertTrue(URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(url)); // returns false
    }

    // this is a local copy of isHttpsUrl:
    // it is simple copied from the original URLUtil (SDK 25)
    private boolean isHttpsUrl(String url) {
    return (null != url) &&
            (url.length() > 7) &&
            url.substring(0, 8).equalsIgnoreCase("https://");
    }
```

As you can see, I have simply copied the `URLUtil.isHttpsUrl()` from the `android.webkit` package.

I have used it with `compileSdkVersion 25` and `compileSdkVersion 24`.
Same happens with `URLUtil.isHttpUrl()

I already tried to clean + rebuild the project, restarted + invalidated cache of AS.

**Can someone explain what is going on? Am I doing something wrong?**

**Or could there be a problem with the Unittest class?** 
It is a simple a JUnit Test and I have set the `returnDefaultValues` in the gradle like this:

```
    android {
      ...
      ...
      testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
      }
    }
```

Although, I would have assumed that "context-related" calls would get default values, but the `URLUtil.isHttpsUrl()`is static and does not involve any context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, it seems like even static Util classes need an Instrumented Unit Test. I just tested it without the `testOptions` and now it says `Method isHttpsUrl in android.webkit.URLUtil not mocked.`

Sorry for bothering you, I've just realized that it could have something to do with the `testOptions` when I was ready to post my question. After 2 hours of debugging and nearly losing my faith in my programming skills.

Hope someone can use this answer though and don't waste so much time on a simple Unittest case.

Comment: strangest thing is, I am also using "URLEncoder.encode(...)" which is part of Android SDK, and related unittests are working without any mocking..